# Laptop for machine learning jobs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, hardware, memory

I am buying a new laptop for data science and web development jobs.

Which combination is better:

- i9 (12900H) & NVIDIA T600 4GB
- or i7 (12800H) & NVIDIA RTX1000A 4GB?
  Both run on a [DELL Precision 3571 workstation](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/workstations/precision-15-3571-laptop/spd/precision-15-3571-laptop?%7Eck=bt) with 32GB.

Comment: That really depends on what sort of ML models you plan to train and test, and how big is your dataset

Comment: tbh, it won't matter if you go for either of these, because from where I see, both are very powerful systems and both are capable of running DL projects locally; however, both will throw immense amount of heat and noise.

Answer (score 0):

The laptops are similar enough, that I would go with the cheaper one, but since you are starting out (I am assuming smaller datasets) and you want to do webdev, I would rather go with the I9, it will maybe be like 5% faster and the GPU is unlikely going to make a massive difference.

Answer (score 0):

For data science and web development tasks, both combinations are capable of handling most of the tasks with ease. However, the i9 (12900H) and NVIDIA T600 4GB combination would likely be better for data science workloads that require high CPU performance, such as running complex machine learning models, data preprocessing, and intensive calculations.

On the other hand, the i7 (12800H) and NVIDIA RTX1000A 4GB combination may be better suited for tasks that require more powerful graphics processing, such as gaming, 3D modelling, and video editing.

That being said, choosing between the two options depends on your specific use case and budget. If your primary focus is on data science and web development tasks, then the i9 and NVIDIA T600 4GB combination would be the better choice. However, if you also plan to use the laptop for graphics-intensive tasks, the i7 and NVIDIA RTX1000A 4GB combination may be a better option.